# What the easiest way to find element with many parameters?

Tags: angularjs, xpath, css-selectors, protractor

I'm trying to find all the methods that can help me find elements with multiple attributes. For example I have a view like this:

```
<span class="n-check ng-isolate-scope ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-model="my_model" my_sp_at="1" my_attribute="my_attribute_value" tabindex="0">...</span>
```

And I want to find the element with attributes "my_sp_at" and "my_attribute". And I'm not sure if the easiest way to find it, is using by.xPath().

```
element(by.xpath("//span[@my_sp_at='1' and @my_attribute='my_attribute_value']
```

I'm wondering whether I can use by.css() with many parameters or something like this?

My goal is maximum avoiding of reading marking, names of Tags and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a so called [Attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to find an element using `by.css()`. So applying it to your requirements, the result would look like:

```
var el = element(by.css('span[my_sp_at="1"][my_attribute="my_attribute_value"]'));
```

or using a shortcut for `element(by.css())` - `$`:

```
var el = $('span[my_sp_at="1"][my_attribute="my_attribute_value"]');
```

It allows to use pretty the same syntax as you would use with jQuery or `document.querySelector[All]`. Basically an attribute selector should be wrapped into square brackets, if you want to use multiple attribute selectors to target the same element, then you should place them one after another without spaces:

```
div.some-class[name="phone"][title="Phone number"]
 ^      ^           ^                  ^
tag   class   attr selector #1    attr selector #2
```

for a tag in your HTML:

```
<div class="some-class" name="phone" title="Phone number"></div>
```

Comment: tl;dr it's not all that different from XPath attribute predicates besides the @ and the way they are chained.